# Change fragment from clickable textview

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragments, in them I want to place custom textview, so I have not to define them everytime.
So when I define the custom textview class I'd like to define a private onClickListener. When the user click on the textview the fragment will bu substituted. In the method onClick inside onClickLister i cannot invoke getFragmentManager. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually as it's a really bad design - to bind item behaviour to objects it does not have to know about.

Just define a class, that implements `OnClickListener` the interface, getting the fragmentManager as a parameter of a constructor and perform all needed actions in this class.
Then simply bind a listener's instance to the TextView in any object wich has a reference to a `FragmentManager`.

Comment: So, if it's a bad design, tell how i can do it in another way. I want to make it in a good way! please show me it

Comment: @AntonelloGatto as I said, the `OnClickListener`(which you want to be private) must be external of TextView-class. It may be an anonymous type or some class, but it must be defined in some class which can get a reference to a `FragmentManager` instance. Thus, in the `OnClickListener` you would be able to define proper fragment transaction. Then just assign the listener to a custom `TextView` and the job is done.

Comment: can you please make me a code example? I'm tryin' it but i can't.